# Wordpress get_the_excerpt with ID number return current page

Tags: php, wordpress

For a website I'm working on, my clients would like to sometimes link other posts within a post in Wordpress. I found this [tutorial](https://www.doitwithwp.com/include-a-post-within-a-post-or-page/#comment-68391) and tried to adapt my code to make it work for my need. Here's what I have so far :

```
function linkarticles($atts) {
  $thepostid = intval($atts[id]);
  $output = '';
  $post = get_post($thepostid);
  if ($post) :
    $output .= '<article class="articles_miniatures"> <a class="img_intro" href="' . get_the_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive']) . '</a><h2>' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</h2>' . get_the_excerpt($post->ID) . '</article>';
  else :
  // failed, output nothing
  endif;
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode('include_post', 'linkarticles');
```

Everything works fine except for the excerpt, which displays the current page excerpt instead of the article with the ID. 
Anyone knows how to fix that ?

Here's a gist of my current [code](http://gist.github.com/Soph87/1b45029128b377859a19c36daf75fb6).

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the required ID in temporarily to see if it then displays the required excerpt? Just as a starting debug step... Also as per the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) you could try passing the WP_Post object to the 'get_the_excerpt' rather than the post id. See if that works.

Comment: I maybe should have explained that I'm very new to php, I understand some of the code that I read but I'm not able to write it on my own yet. Could you explain a bit more what I should do, maybe with code examples?

Comment: replace `get_the_excerpt($post->ID)` with `get_the_excerpt($post)`

Comment: Still not working, I get the excerpt for the current page.

Comment: Can you do a gist or codepen or fiddle with the full page code.

Comment: I'm not sure what code I could share since it's for a wordpress site... This function is in my functions.php file, I then add the shortcode it creates in my post in the admin part of wp. How can I make it work in gist?

Comment: I just want to see all the relevant code, so that I can see the whole picture.

Comment: Here it is : https://gist.github.com/Soph87/1b45029128b377859a19c36daf75fb60

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you are using the 'include_post' shortcode. How are you using the shortcode? Also do you have a link to the page that this code is running on?

Comment: I only have it running locally. I use the shortcode in wp admin inside posts, that's why you don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Shows us how you call the shortcode.

Comment: Ok, I see this line in your code: `$post = get_post($thepostid);` Then you use $post to get the various post elements. This could be causing a clash with the $post created as part of the WP loop. Try changing your $post variable to $relPost and then have your code use this new variable name.